# ArcGIS Pro. Remove folder connection, Database connection, toolboxes with ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro

I'm trying to remove all unnecessary connections in ArcGIS Pro with ArcPy.  I'm running a script which picks up ArcGIS Pro Project template and makes a copy. Then adds new database and toolbox  and makes these things as the default ones.
But when I open newly created ArcGIS Pro aprx, database, toolbox and folder connection from **template** are still there. How can I remove them?

Part of my script:

```
import arcpy

aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("path to template") #path to ArcGIS Pro template 
database=arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(Path,Name) #create database  
aprx.defaultGeodatabase=database  #set default database  
aprx.homeFolder="Path to folder"  #set default folder connection 
aprx.saveACopy(new.aprx)
```

Comment: Perhaps they are amongst your Favorites in the Catalog pane.

Comment: Thanks @PolyGeo. But not really. There is nothing in my favorites.  If i delete for instance toolbox and database from template folder, as soon as I open template aprx, these two reappear.   I think its an ESRI thing.   I can however set up default home folder, toolbox and  database in my newly created aprx, but i cannot remove the old ones.

Comment: Perhaps review https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/236262/115

Answer (score 1):

(I work at Esri)

From some planning documents, I see "Add/remove folders and databases" (connections) as a targeted item in the *near term*. From that, I can infer that there is no `arcpy.mp` command to simply remove these from the project. There still might be a way to accomplish this, but you won't find a straightforward arcpy command to do it.

Note - *near term* usually means within the next release or two (3.1 or 3.2), but priorities can change at any time, so this is no guarantee.